# Hyphen with strings in PROC FORMAT

Tags: string, sas

I am working with IC9 codes and am creating somewhat of a mapping between codes and an integer:

```
proc format library = &formatlib;

    invalue category other = 0

        '410'-'410.99', '425.4'-'425.99' = 1
```

I have [searched](https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/proc/zalrange.htm) and [searched](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/69850/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n03qskwoints2an1ispy57plwrn9.htm), but haven't been able to find an explanation of how that range actually works when it comes to formatting.

Take the first range, for example. I assume SAS interprets `'410'-'410.99'` as "take every value between the inclusive range [410, 410.99] and convert it to a `1`. Please correct me if I'm wrong in that assumption. Does SAS treat these seeming strings as floating-point decimals, then? I think that must be the case if these are to be numerical ranges for formatting all codes within the range.

I'm coming to SAS from the worlds of R and Python, and thus the way quote characters are used in SAS sometimes is unclear (like when using `%let foo = bar`... not quotes are used).

Comment: Note your last example (`%let foo=bar;`) is the SAS macro language, which is a _totally different_ language from the rest of SAS - hence why no quotes (in the macro language, *everything* is text, you can only do math/etc. when you tell SAS to hope the macro text can evaluate to a numeric value and there is zero type safety).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SAS compares string values with normal comparison operators, what it does is compare the byte representation of each character in the string, one at a time, until it reaches a difference.

So what you're going to see here is when a string is input, it will be compared to the 'start' string and, if greater than start, then compared to the 'end' string, and if less than end, evaluated to a 1; if it's not for each pair listed, then evaluated to a zero.

Importantly, this means that some nonsensical results could occur - see the last row of the following test, for example.

```
proc format;
    invalue category other = 0
        '410'-'410.99', '425.4'-'425.99' = 1
    ;
quit;

data test;
  input @1 testval $6.;
  category=input(testval,category.);
  datalines;
425.23
425.45
425.40
410#
410.00
410.AA
410.7A
;;;;
run;
```

`410.7A` is compared to `410` and found greater, as '4'='4', '1'='1', '0'='0', '.' > ' ', so greater . Then `410.7A` is compared to `410.99` and found less, as  '4'='4', '1'='1', '0'='0', '7' < '9', so less.  The `A` is irrelevant to the comparison. But on the row above it you see it's not in the sequence, since `A` is ASCII 41x and that is not less than '9' (ASCII 39x).

Note that all SAS strings are filled to their full length by spaces.  This can be important in string comparisons, because space is the lowest-valued printable character (if you consider space printable).  Thus any character you're likely to compare to space will be higher - so for example the fourth row (`410#`) is a 1 because `#` is between  and `.` in the ASCII table!  But change that to `/` and it fails.  Similarly, change it to `byte(13)` (through code) and it fails - because it is then *less* than space (so `410^M`, with `^M` representing byte(13), is less than start (`410`)).  In informats and formats, SAS will treat the format/informat start/end as being whatever the length that it needs to - so if you're reading a 6 long string, it will treat it as length 6 and fill the rest with spaces.

Comment: Well, the good thing is that I won't be dealing with comparing any alphanumeric strings - just numeric. Great explanation, thank you.

Comment: That's more of a caution... while ICD10 codes shouldn't have alphas in them, if they come from text entry I wouldn't use a range format to ensure they're accurate.